# c#-UserControl with a button and multiple actions (winforms)

Tags: c#, oop, user-controls, delegates

I am working on a c# winform app and I want to use one UserControl. My userControl contains one label and one button.

My question is: Having one form, and using the same UserControl many times, how can my button from UserControl do different actions?

[image: http://imgur.com/wJIroa2]

Comment: are these actions sequential? ie. a "next/back" setup

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event to your user control (e.g. 'ButtonClicked'), implement a button on click method in your user control code, and in that method, fire the `ButtonClicked` event. e.g.

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
  .
  .
  .
  public event EventHandler ButtonClick;
  .
  .
  .
  private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (ButtonClick != null)
     {
        ButtonClick(sender, e);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: And then set the handler for `ButtonClick` event through properties window or form `Load` event in the calling `Form`.